# BS4 Python get a href url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I stacked with on bs4 script, I need to get href link or meta content, how I could that? Basically I need to get this :

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://resources.reed.co.uk/profileimages/logos/thumbs/Logo_71709.png?v=20200828172950">
```

or

```
<img src="https://resources.reed.co.uk/profileimages/logos/thumbs/Logo_71709.png?v=20200828172950" alt="Posted by Publica Group " width="120" height="50" class=" b-loaded" style="display: inline;">
```

I tried do that with :

```
            logoscrap = soup.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'image'})
```

and

```
            logoscrap = soup.find('img', class_="b-loaded").attrs['src']
```

But my code isn't work...

Comment: Can you share URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soup.find return dict object you can directly acces attibute from dict

```
img = soup.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'image'})
logoscrap = img['content']
#output:
https://resources.reed.co.uk/profileimages/logos/thumbs/Logo_71709.png?v=20200828172950
```

or

```
img = soup.find('img', class_="b-loaded")
logoscrap  = img['src']
#output:
https://resources.reed.co.uk/profileimages/logos/thumbs/Logo_71709.png?v=20200828172950
```

Comment: cool, You can mark it correct if it worked so others can also take advantage :)